# Is it possible to drag and drop between windows in a visionOS app?

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos

App has two window:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DataMapperVOSApp: App {
    var sharedState = SharedState()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(sharedState).colorScheme(.dark)
            
        }
        
        WindowGroup (id: "SecondWindow"){
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(sharedState).colorScheme(.dark)
        }

        ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
            ImmersiveView()
        }
    }
}
```

And here the second is opened:

```
Button(action: {
                    openWindow(id: "SecondWindow")
                    print("Show Second Window")
                }) {
                    Text("Show Second Window")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
```

But I do not know how to drag and drop from one to the other. Is it even possible?